# Activiti JSF Spring

Tags: spring, jsf-2, activiti, bpmn

i'm beginner!
when run xhtml page ----> Error:
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Line Number 1, Column 1
!!!!
i used tomcat server
Spring-Activiti.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                           ">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="databaseType" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true"/>
        <property name="deploymentResources"
                  value="classpath*:bookorder.spring.bpmn20.xml"/>
        <property name="history" value="audit"/>
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getRepositoryService"/>
    <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getRuntimeService"/>
    <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getTaskService"/>
    <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getHistoryService"/>
    <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getManagementService"/>

    <bean id="order" class="activiti.OrderService"/>

</beans>
```

Faces-config:

```
<application>
        <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.SpringBeanVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
        <variable-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
        </variable-resolver>
    </application>
```

web.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <!-- ************************* Spring  Related *********************************** -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/Spring-Activiti.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- ************************* Faces Related  *********************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            20
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

I found a piece of code that is causing the error

```
 <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getRepositoryService"/>
    <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getRuntimeService"/>
    <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getTaskService"/>
    <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getHistoryService"/>
    <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine"
          factory-method="getManagementService"/>
```

Please help me!
thak u

Answer (score 0):

Your file is missing the xml header: < ? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ? >
 (Delete the spaces before the question mark)